# redis pub sub and ttl

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

Is there a way so that I expire a "published" message in redis?

I need this because, as per my understanding, any published message will be put in a queue till there is a subscriber. In such a case if there is no subscriber, I am storing the data even after it may have become useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Published message never store in redis. [Redis PUB/SUB](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to think about is: you can always add a timestamp inside your messages' string representation.   Then, even if a consumer gets a message but doesn't process it on time, it can ignore it.

Also, as Ganesh mentioned the pubsub queue doesn't store messages.